# How this integral is calculated?

Tags: calculus, integration

In a correction I don't understand how this integral is computed. Can someone help me ?

We have $\psi_1(t) = \mathbf{1}\{t \in [0,1]\}$ and
$$
\mathbb{E}[N(t)N(t-\tau)] = \begin{cases} 
1 - |\tau|, &|\tau| < 1 \\
0 &\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

[image]

Comment: I am not sure to understand what is $N$. When you write
$$\mathbb E[N(t)N(t - \tau)]$$
you mean
$$\int_\Omega N(t)(\omega)N(t - \tau)(\omega) d\mathbb P(\omega) ~?$$

Comment: Apologies, I should have written this more clearly, $N$ is a gaussian process with autocorrelation function $\mathbb{E}[N(t)N(t-\tau)]$